# Backbone.js - Fetch with a php proxy - proxy not interpreted?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, proxy, fetch

I'm trying to fetch a collection from a RSS feed. It's XML data. I ran into the cross domain problem, so I have set up a proxy. The fetch is always returning an error saying "parsererror". I think it is because my proxy is not interpreted. Here is my code below:

```
var OfferCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: OfferModel,
    url: 'proxy.php',

    parse: function(resp){
        var dataArray = [];
        $(resp).find('item').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        dataArray.push({title: title});
     });
     return dataArray;
    },

    getOffers: function(){
        this.fetch({
            cache: false,
            success: function(collection, response, options){
                console.log('OK');
            },
            error: function(collection, response, options){
                console.log(response.responseText);
                console.log(options);
                console.log(collection);
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my proxy.php file:

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: application/xml');
 $url = 'my_rss_feed_link';
 $handle = fopen($url, "r");

 if ($handle) {
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    echo $buffer;
 }
 fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

So everytime it goes in the error callback where responseText is a string containing exactly my proxy.php file and of course textStatus is equal to parsererror because the response is not xml.

I don't understand why my proxy file is not interpreted. If someone has already encounter this problem, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

ah I think i read your question wrong...

you need to check your server settings to see if your php is working.
It's not backbone's fault if your server is not executing the php file

what server environment you are using? can you access the php file in your browser and see what's being returned?

if you are developing in a local environment, you may wanna try WAMP or XAMPP

=============

backbone, by default, expects a json response.

You will want to set the "datatype" of the ajax calls to 'xml' in order to use any service that returns xml.

add the dataType setting like this:

```
this.fetch({
  dataType: 'xml'
});
```

or, if all of your services return xml, you will want to overwrite the Backbone.sync method.

==== or, in your model:

```
fetch: function (options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.dataType = "xml";
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

here's an example i used in another question i answered: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/4/

========**EDIT**:=============

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/7/

you should see your collection in the console.

ignore 'data' and 'type' parameters in the fetch method, they are just for jsfiddle's echo service.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tried it and it doesn't change anything. I still have the same response/error.

Comment: it works for me. could you post your response? here's the fiddle i updated for your case: http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/6/   it parses the response correctly.

Comment: edit:  you will have to check your server settings. what web server you are using for your php environment.

Comment: I have added the custom fetch in my collection to set the dataType to xml. But I still get these responses:
responseText: the exact content of my proxy.php file
textStatus: parsererror probably because responseText is a string
I think the problem is coming from the use of a proxy. In your fiddle you're using a local file.

EDIT: I'm using apache2

Comment: in the jsfiddle it's not a local file, it's using jsfiddle's echo service. the issue you have here is because your server is not executing the php, you have to make sure your server is configured correctly for php environment.

Comment: if you are developing in a local environment, you may wanna try WAMP or XAMPP

Comment: My web server should be configured correctly because I have developed some Symfony2 projects before. But you're right, there is probably a configuration that I'm missing to use this proxy file...

Comment: You were right thanks! PHP module for apache was not loaded. It works now with only setting dataType to xml.